# How to select a record defined in a package in sql query

Tags: oracle, plsql

to test the code:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b02671a25f9d7949e0b55ca59084ecd1

If I define a record as an object, I can call it in a sql statement this way objectname(field1, field2)
But If I define a record inside package as a record. I can't do that anymore.

```
create TYPE arguments_r IS  object
(
    q    integer,
    b    INTEGER
);

CREATE FUNCTION f (p IN arguments_r) RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END;
/
select arguments_r(1,1) from dual  -- not printed but exists nevertheless. THe following statement prove it.

select f(arguments_r(1,1)) from dual --print the expected result
```

---

```
CREATE PACKAGE pck
as

TYPE arguments_r IS  record
(
    q    integer,
    b    INTEGER
);

FUNCTION f (p IN pck.arguments_r) RETURN INTEGER;

end;

CREATE PACKAGE body pck 
as

FUNCTION f (p IN pck.arguments_r) RETURN INTEGER
is 
begin
 return 1;
end;

END;

select pck.arguments_r(1,1) from dual  -- ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ARGUMENTS_R'
```

Answer (score 2):

[TL;DR] In general, you cannot.

A record is a PL/SQL **ONLY** data type and it **CANNOT** be used in SQL. If you want to use the data in SQL then you will need to put it into an SQL data type such as an `Object`.

There are ways of achieving what you want via `PIPELINED` functions (which implicitly convert a `RECORD` to an `OBJECT` so, technically you never use a PL/SQL data type in the SQL scope but it certainly looks like you do) but the implementation is convoluted and if I ever did a code review on code that tried to use records the way I show below then I would fail it in the review and tell the author to just use an SQL `OBJECT`.

---

Given the setup:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE pck as
  TYPE args_r IS  record (
    q    integer,
    b    INTEGER
  );

  TYPE args_t IS TABLE OF args_r;
  
  FUNCTION f RETURN args_t PIPELINED;
  FUNCTION f2 RETURN args_t;

  FUNCTION create_arg(q INTEGER, b INTEGER) RETURN args_t PIPELINED;
  FUNCTION create_arg2(q INTEGER, b INTEGER) RETURN args_t;
  FUNCTION g(args IN args_r) RETURN INTEGER;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY pck as
  FUNCTION f RETURN args_t PIPELINED
  IS 
  BEGIN
    PIPE ROW (args_r(1,1));
    PIPE ROW (args_r(2,2));
  END;

  FUNCTION f2 RETURN args_t
  IS 
  BEGIN
    RETURN args_t(args_r(1,1), args_r(2,2));
  END;

  FUNCTION create_arg(q INTEGER, b INTEGER) RETURN args_t PIPELINED
  IS
  BEGIN
    PIPE ROW (args_r(q, b));
  END;

  FUNCTION create_arg2(q INTEGER, b INTEGER) RETURN args_t
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN args_t(args_r(q, b));
  END;

  FUNCTION g(args IN args_r) RETURN INTEGER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN args.q;
  END;
END;
/
```

#### From PL/SQL to SQL via a `PIPELINED` function:

If you want to pass PL/SQL records from a PL/SQL function into an SQL query then it will "work" (see the comment below for clarification of why) if you use a `PIPELINED` function then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(pck.f());
```

Outputs:

> | Q | B |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 |

**BUT** that is not because you can use PL/SQL records in SQL it is because a `PIPELINED` function is intended to be used in the SQL scope so Oracle has implicitly created a duplicate `OBJECT` data type (and `TABLE OF ...` data type) and mapped the PL/SQL record to the SQL object and despite what the signature of the function says, it is not returning records and returning Objects instead.

#### From PL/SQL to SQL via a function returning a collection:

If you try to do exactly the same thing with a non-`PIPELINED` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(pck.f2());
```

Then you get the error:

> ```
> ORA-00902: invalid datatype
> ```

Because no such implicit conversion has been applied and you **CANNOT** use PL/SQL record types in SQL.

#### From SQL to PL/SQL:

Going the other way, as per the question, and trying to create records in the SQL scope and pass them to a PL/SQL function then it **CANNOT** work because it is impossible to create PL/SQL records in the SQL scope.

The query:

```sql
SELECT pck.g(pck.args_r(1,1))
FROM   DUAL;
```

Fails with the error:

> ```
> ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ARGS_R'
> ```

#### From PL/SQL to SQL back to PL/SQL via a `PIPELINED` function:

If you create the record in PL/SQL and return it via a `PIPELINED` function then it "works":

```sql
SELECT pck.g((SELECT VALUE(t) FROM TABLE(pck.create_arg(1,1)) t))
FROM   DUAL;
```

and outputs:

> | PCK.G((SELECTVALUE(T)FROMTABLE(PCK.CREATE_ARG(1,1))T)) |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

#### From PL/SQL to SQL back to PL/SQL via a function returning a collection:

However, if you use a non-`PIPELINED` function:

```sql
SELECT pck.g((SELECT VALUE(t) FROM TABLE(pck.create_arg2(1,1)) t))
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then it raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00902: invalid datatype
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=79571ea83f5f8c5bc2c5037d19cdce22)*

#### Conclusion:

Just define an `OBJECT` data type; do not try to use convoluted methods to ram PL/SQL only data types into an SQL scope where they are not meant to be used.